# Problems with making openerp 7 work with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, odoo, pydev, openerp-7

I followed the steps to open the OpenERP 7 folder as a project in Eclipse.

I already installed PyDev, and I am using Python Interpreter version 2.7.

When I opened purchase.py, it gave me errors on some import lines. Upon further research, I found that I have to add external libraries from Project > Properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH > External Libraries > Add Source Folder.

Example: Error at import pytz, so I added the pytz folder inside OpenERP7>Sever>server

However that did not fix the problem. When I tried to Run the purchse.py file, it gave me this error:

"ImportError: Bad magic number in C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140202-002512\Server\server\os.pyc"

I researched and it said I should delete the .pyc file and build again, however that only made it do the same error on another .pyc file.

I am running Eclipse as an Administrator, and I am running the correct version of th Python Interpreter (which are the two problems suggested to be linked to the "Bad magic number" error I faced earlier.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix these issues?

Comment: Can you please paste the exact errors you are getting on each of the erroneous steps? Also, delete all the `.pyc` files for which you still have the equivalent `.py` files in your directory tree.

Comment: I deleted all of the .pyc files, and I no longer have the bad magic number error, however now I have this:
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140202-002512\Server\server\openerp\addons\purchase\purchase.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pytz
ImportError: No module named pytz
"
I added the pytz folder into the PythonPath as I stated above and it did not help.

Comment: To add, I already tried to do this as well:  

`import sys`
  
`sys.path.append("_location_")`

Comment: Try explicitly installing the modules. You can see more information here: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I will have to try that. There are over 30-40 instances of this error on different modules. So this is going to be a real pain. Thanks for your help. I'll let you know what happens.